# Strange behavior with HttpWebRequest in C# console application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, httpwebrequest, threadpool

I have a simple console application that sends a number of POST requests to a server and prints out the average successful requests per second. The application makes use of the HttpWebRequest class to do the actual message sending. It is multi-threaded and leverages the C# ThreadPool.

I have tested this application on a server that immediately sends a response back and one that actually does some work. In the former scenario, a single instance of my application is able to achieve around 30k messages a second. In the later scenario around 12k messages a second.

The strange behavior I am observing is that if I run multiple instances (2-4) of my application I achieve a greater accumulative throughput than if I were to run a single instance. Thus for the two scenarios described above I achieve an accumulated throughput of 40k and 20k respectively.

What I cannot figure out is why a single instance of my application cannot achieve the 20k throughput in the second scenario if a single instance of my application has been proven to achieve a throughput of 30k in the first scenario.

I have played around with the maxconnection parameter as well as the various threadpool parameters e.g. minthreads / maxthreads. I have also tried altering the implementation e.g. Parallel.For / Task.Run / ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem. I have even tested an asynchronous paradigm. Unfortunately, all versions exhibit the same behavior.

Any idea what could be going on?

**EDIT**

The main loop looks as follows:

```
Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    _throttle.WaitOne();
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(SendStressMessage);
                }
            });
```

Ripping out the unecessary bits of SendStressMessage, looks like this:

```
private static void SendStressMessage(Object state)
        {

            var message = _sampleMessages.ElementAt(_random.Next(_sampleMessages.Count));

            if (SendMessage(_stressuri, message))
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref _successfulMessages);
                _sucessfulMessageCounter.Increment();
                _QPSCounter.Increment();
            }
            else
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref _failedMessages);
                _failedMessageCounter.Increment();
            }
            // Check time of last QPS read out
            if (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(_lastPrint).TotalSeconds > _printDelay)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    // Check one last time while holding the lock
                    if (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(_lastPrint).TotalSeconds > _printDelay)
                    {
                        // Print current QPS and update last print / successful message count
                        Console.WriteLine("Current QPS: " + (int)((Thread.VolatileRead(ref _successfulMessages) - _lastSuccessfulMessages) / DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(_lastPrint).TotalSeconds));
                        _lastSuccessfulMessages = _successfulMessages;
                        _lastPrint = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    }
                }
            }

            _throttle.Release();
        }
```

Finally, the sendmessage method looks as follows:

```
private static bool SendMessage(Uri uri, byte[] message)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.ContentLength = message.Length;

            // Write to request body
            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
            }

            // Try posting message
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            // Check response status and increment accordingly
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Dispose of response
            if (response != null)
            {
                response.Close();
                response.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

If you notice above, there is a lock. I have tried removing the lock and this does not affect performance.

**UPDATE**

As stated above, I initially experienced poor performance when I rewrote the application to be asynchronous. I had not realized that the implementation was incorrect as I was in fact blocking on an IO call. As pointed out by @David d C e Freitas, there is an async version of  GetRequestStream which I was not utilizing. Finally, my initial implementation did not throttle the number of pending messages. This greatly reduced performance as too many async handles were being created.

An outline of the final solution which does not exhibit the issues described above follows:

The main loop:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await _throttle.WaitAsync();
                SendStressMessageAsync();
            }
        });
```

A stripped down version of SendStressMessageAsync() follows:

```
private static async void SendStressMessageAsync()
    {

        var message = _sampleMessages.ElementAt(_random.Next(_sampleMessages.Count));

        if (await SendMessageAsync(_stressuri, message))
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _successfulMessages);
            _sucessfulMessageCounter.Increment();
            _QPSCounter.Increment();
        }
        else
        {
            //Failed request - increment failed count
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _failedMessages);
            _failedMessageCounter.Increment();
        }
        // Check time of last QPS read out
        if (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(_lastPrint).TotalSeconds > _printDelay)
        {
            await _printlock.WaitAsync();
            // Check one last time while holding the lock
            if (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(_lastPrint).TotalSeconds > _printDelay)
            {
                // Print current QPS and update last print / successful message count
                Console.WriteLine("Current QPS: " + (int)(Interlocked.Read(ref _successfulMessages) / DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(_startTime).TotalSeconds));
                _lastPrint = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
            _printlock.Release();
        }

        _throttle.Release();
    }
```

Finally the async send message looks as follows:

```
private static async Task<bool> SendMessageAsync(Uri uri, byte[] message)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            // Create POST request to provided VIP / Port
            request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.ContentLength = message.Length;

            // Write to request body
            using (Stream requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
            {
                requestStream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
            }

            // Try posting message
            response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();

            // Check response status and increment accordingly
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //Failed request - increment failed count
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Dispose of response
            if (response != null)
            {
                response.Close();
                response.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is you are simply not using your resources enough, until you run several instances. Using parallel or async doesn't magically speed up your application, you need to place them at the right place where there's a bottleneck.

The specific problem is you probably used parallel, but you needed a bigger degree of parallelism because the nature of your operation isn't CPU-Intensive but I/O-Intensive.
You can use both parallel and async together to fully utilize your resources.

That's all I can do without any specific code.

Comment: I am surely not using all the resources available on my test computer. I have monitored my system while the application is running and I am using at most a quarter of the system. Like I have said, I have tried messing around with the threadpool and ensure there are more active threads. After a certain limit, this actually degrades the performance of my application. I'll try and post some code examples to see if you can help out. I have not attempted to both parallel and async together.

Comment: @grouma adding more threads to the thread pool doesn't increase the degree of parallelism. You need to configure that using the TPL. The thread count should actually be quite small.

Comment: Using both async and TPL together means you can fire many async handlers while using much fewer threads.

Comment: I should have been more clear. When I said more active threads, I was referring to altering this parameter: ThreadPool.SetMinThreads. In the Window's performance monitor you can see the number of threads for a given process. This parameter does in fact directly increase that number.

Comment: @grouma I know. That only increases the amount of available threads. Even if you don't change it and your application needs threads from the threadpool it will automatically create more threads. It's doesn't affect the TPL or the degree of parallelism of your parallel foreach/for.

Comment: I see. Let me mess around with the configurations within TPL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The .NET framework limits the number of connections made to a particular host, using an application configuration item [maxconnections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tkaca2y).  By default this limit is 2 connections per host.

What this means is that with the default settings only 2 requests can be active at any time.  If you initiate 10 requests at once only 2 of them will connect immediately.  The rest will spin until one of the available slots becomes free.

Try modifying your `App.config` to include the following:

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <connectionManagement>
            <add address = "*" maxconnection = "10" />
        </connectionManagement>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

This will allow 10 connections per host, which should greatly improve your throughput.

Comment: I have already altered my app.config to contain this setting. It is currently sitting at 1000. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your question is:
Why does a request that does nothing return up to 30kmsg/s and a request that does some work returns 12kmsg/s?

Can you see how many requests are in a waiting state (in-flight) on your test application? i.e. how many have opened the socket and fully written the request out but haven't started receiving some data back. 
Perhaps your test application can only handle so many "in-progress" requests at a time before it slows down the pending queue.

So this question is about the server and not your test client application, as the server is what is determining how many requests it can handle per second more likely than your test application.  What is the server written in, what have you tweaked there?

Update:

One thing to consider is that there are many synchronous operations happening behind the scenes that you aren't handling:

1. Sync DNS lookup for the address. (Try using the IP)
2. The TCP connection setup/startup time (opening a connection).

   - GetRequestStream can be done async, i.e. BeginGetRequestStream
   - GetResponse can be done async, i.e. BeginGetResponse or GetResponseAsync

Blocking on any of these actions will limit your throughput in the single threaded instance.

Comment: The server is written in Java and is based on Netty. It uses a LinkedBlockingQueue to enqueue work and a consumer pool to execute this work. It comes as no surprise that doing work limits the overall throughput. The surprise comes from the fact that it takes multiple instances of my application to saturate the servers throughput when it should take only one.

Comment: @grouma, OK, I remembered that there other blocking operations occurring that you aren't handling to maximize throughput.  I've added them to the answer above.